# image processing recognizing object digit

Tags: c#, .net, image, aforge

need help with implementation on recognizing characters from a image.
for example i have
[image]

how to recognize 142 489

1. to make images for every digit, map 0 -> [images like 0], 1 -> like 1... and so on.

2. to make only lines of image, i mean

[image]

and compare with images in case 1, or with "skelet" in case 2.
how to implement one of this methods?
using Aforge in c#;

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I don't think captchas were meant to be recognized by computers.

Comment: Captchas make me feel I'm not human anymore: my first guess for the first character would be l (small L). There are several pitfalls when recognising (pixel-)images as alphanumeric: different fonts, high visual similarity for characters. So for words you can use at least a dictionary, but even that cannot give you a clue on the context if there still is an ambiguity. **TL;DR** use an existing solution or spent the next years reading academic papers.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a trivial problem so you may be better to examine an existing implementation like the [.NET wrapper for Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/).